# icloud drive documents not syncing instantly between devices

Tags: ios, swift, icloud, icloud-drive

I have implemented icloud drive using swift. it's code looking good as given in official document and uploading/downloading files with single device perfectly. 
Now when going to download file on another device with same cloud user. its unable to find file in that device. now i have disabled/enabled icloud from device cloud settings after some time then tried again and its worked (now found file on that device).

so here some questions occurs regarding this below.

- is icloud not sync files instantly between devices (if no, then how can we sync files on between device instantly)
- is there any way to notify device for sync new created files on cloud ?
- currently copied files to cloud document not listing on cloud.com. so how can we show/hide copied files on icloud ?

here are code for upload/download files :

**copy file to cloud**

```
if let cloudURL =  FileManager.default.url(forUbiquityContainerIdentifier: nil)?.appendingPathComponent("Documents") {
  let file = cloudURL.appendingPathComponent("file.txt")
  if (FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: file.path, isDirectory: nil)) {
    do{
      try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: file)
    }catch let error as NSError {
      print("error",error)
    }
  }

  let localDocumentsURL = DocumentsDirectory.localDocumentsURL.appendingPathComponent("file.txt")
  do {
    try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: localDocumentsURL, to: file)

  } catch let error as NSError{
    print("can not copy file",error)
  }
}
```

**download file from cloud directory**

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default
    if let cloudURL = fileManager.url(forUbiquityContainerIdentifier: nil)?.appendingPathComponent("Documents") {
      let file = cloudURL.appendingPathComponent("file.txt")
      do{
        var downloded = false
        try fileManager.startDownloadingUbiquitousItem(at: file)
        while(!downloded){
          if(fileManager.fileExists(atPath: file.path, isDirectory: nil)){
            downloded = true
          }
        }
        let filePath = DocumentsDirectory.localDocumentsURL.appendingPathComponent("file.txt")
        try fileManager.copyItem(at: file, to: filePath)
      }catch let error as NSError {
        print("error",error)
      }
    }
```

Comment: Are you using simulator or real devices? Have you tried checking from the 2nd device prior to starting download, if the iCloud Documents directory has the file in it?  i.e. `FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: cloudURL.path)`  I have the same situation and the 2nd device returns false for existence. Struggling to find consistency with this.